# Setting up JDBC Authentication in Jetty

Tags: java, authentication, jdbc, jetty

I need to setup basic jdbc authentication using jetty.

can anyone throw me some pointers (article, tutorial or even some simple solutions)

Comment: What do you mean about JDBC authentication? Do you mean you want to be able to connect to a database and then authenticate based on the data pulled from the database?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [docs for setting up Realms in Jetty](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Realms). Scroll down to "JDBCUserRealm".